YA book about a young girl flies on plane to see father or uncle. She eats a cheese and mayo sandwich and gets sick
My 6th grade teacher read this book to us in 1983 or 1984. Seems like it had a yellow cover. It wasn’t a short story. A girl lives with her mom and travels by plane to see her father or uncle. Mom packed her a cheese and mayonnaise sandwich, but it sits in the sun too long and it spoils and makes her sick. She possibly saw horses or other planes at her dad or uncle’s. It’s not Harriet the Spy.

Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Please see our identification request wiki and, if any of the prompts there jog your memory, please [edit] to add more details. For example: Where was your school located? (Even a country may help) Were there illustrations, and if so, what style? What language was the book in? How large was it (cover area & thickness)? Was there a special occasion for the travel? Why did she have that sandwich specifically? Where did the characters live? What time period the setting?
